# ESC/POS abstraction library in C

Tags: c, escpos

Is there any library in C that provides abstraction over the ESC/POS interface? Meaning, the layout is constructed in a more user friendly way, for example in JSON or any other markup language and then it is converted to an ESC/POS layout. I refuse to believe that no one made such thing, but it seems to be true, I can not find anything.

Comment: [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be a better site to ask about this; see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://github.com/escpos and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P might have something useful, though I haven't looked very closely.

Comment: We did a escpos Lua module to leverage such printers from Lua

Comment: Written in C++, you can find these repositories on GitHub. It may be of some help. [Malanche/escpospp](https://github.com/Malanche/escpospp), [gdsports/ESC_POS_Printer](https://github.com/gdsports/ESC_POS_Printer/tree/master)